# Invalid SESSION ID on Account creation

Tags: rest-api, java

I'm very new to salesforce.

I created a developer account and I am trying to create an account using RESTAPI. I have the error 'Session expired or invalid" but I don't know why. I read a previous post about the same error but I am using the instance_url returned by the server and the access token.

So I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
   public void testSalesForceContactCreation() throws Exception{
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    String path = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

    WebResource serviceEnroll = client.resource(path);
    String security_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    MultivaluedMapImpl formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    formData.add("grant_type", "password");
    formData.add("client_id", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    formData.add("client_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    formData.add("username", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    formData.add("password", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"+security_token);

    ClientResponse response = serviceEnroll.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);

    String result = response.getEntity(String.class);

    JSONObject returned = new JSONObject(result);
    saveAccount(returned.getString("id"), returned.getString("instance_url"), returned.getString("token_type"));
}

private void saveAccount(String accessToken, String instanceURL, String tokenType) throws JSONException{
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);

    JSONObject account = new JSONObject();
    account.put("name", "John");

    WebResource resource = client.resource(instanceURL+ "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/");

    ClientResponse response = resource
            .header("Authorization", tokenType+ " " + accessToken)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(ClientResponse.class, account.toString());


    String result = response.getEntity(String.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorization header should be in the form `Authorization: Bearer {token}` so change

```
.header("Authorization", tokenType+ " " + accessToken)
```

to be

```
.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
```